Can't configure sending emails using smtp in Django
I work in a large company that has its own smtp server.
I can't configure Django to work properly with this server.
Emails are sent if the following settings are in my settings.py:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = '22.2.22.22' (I changed IP)
    EMAIL_PORT = 25
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''

But I don't use username and password. It should probably be like this?:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = '22.2.22.22' (I changed IP)
    EMAIL_PORT = 25
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'USER'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD'

But if I write like this, I have errors: ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for '22.2.22.22'.
If i change: EMAIL_USE_TLS = False, I have errors: smtplib.SMTPException: No suitable authentication method found.
How do I write correctly in the settings.py?
